# Angular JS complex tree view

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a complex JSON. can I use this to create a tree view.Here is  sample json.  A project can have tasks, subprojects and can go to any depth.

`$scope.data = [{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "node1",
      "TaskNodes" : [
            {
              "id": 113,
              "title": "Parent Task node1.1.3",
            "TaskNodes": [{
                "id": 1131,
              "title": "Child Task node1.1.3",
            "TaskNodes": []

              }]
            }
          ],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "title": "node1.1",
          "TaskNodes" : [
            {
              "id": 112,
              "title": "Task node1.1.2",
              "TaskNodes": []
            }
          ],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "id": 111,
              "title": "node1.1.1",
              "nodes": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "title": "node1.2",
          "nodes": []
        }
      ],
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "node2",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 21,
          "title": "node2.1",
          "nodes": []
        },
        {
          "id": 22,
          "title": "node2.2",
          "nodes": []
        }
      ],
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "node3",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": 31,
          "title": "node3.1",
          "nodes": []
        }
      ],
    }];
  });`

this is the render html using angular-ui-tree

```
<!-- Nested node template -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
          <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="node.nodes && node.nodes.length > 0" nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
            {{node.title}}
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
          </div>
          <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
            <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="TaskNodes_renderer.html">
          <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-if="TaskNode.TaskNodes && TaskNode.TaskNodes.length > 0" nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
            {{TaskNode.title}}
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
          </div>
          <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="TaskNode.TaskNodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
            <li ng-repeat="TaskNode in TaskNode.TaskNodes" ui-tree-node ng-include="'TaskNodes_renderer.html'">
            </li>
          </ol>
        </script>

        <div ui-tree id="tree-root">
          <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="data">
            <li ng-repeat="TaskNode in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'TaskNodes_renderer.html'"></li>      

            <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I need to create a tree view for this. i have found a lot of them for one children type but in my case its a  double chidlren type.

Any help is appreciated. thanks.
Sanjeev

Comment: You'll need to let us know what you've tried so far. Did you know that the ng-repeat directive can be nested? I'd start there.

Comment: also not hard to map your data to a format that another directive uses. Without some code it's very hard to tell where your problems are

Comment: i have edited what I have done so far. It doesn pickup the TaskNodes parallel to nodes but when displaying it keeps it outside of that nodes.